# Multiprocess with Tkinter in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, multiprocessing

I am quite new to python. Recently, I learnt some of the advanced concepts like Multiprocessing, Threading and GUI using Tkinter.

I am trying my hands dirty on simple project.

The code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import multiprocessing

global paused, lbl
paused = False

def update_label():
    global t
    t = 30
     if not paused and t >= 0:
        lbl.config(text=str(t))
        t -= 1
        lbl.after(1000, update_label)
    elif t < 0:
        lbl.config(text="Time's Up!!")

def pause():
    global paused
    paused = not paused

def main():
    start_timer = str(input("Do you want to start the timer:(Y/N) "))
    if start_timer == 'Y':
        p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=update_label)
        p1.start()
        p1.join()

    pause_timer = str(input("Do you want to pause the timer: (Y/N) "))
    if pause_timer == 'Y':
        p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=pause)
        # paused = True
        p2.start()
        p2.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("400x200")

    lbl = tk.Label(root, bg='red', fg='black', font=("Arial", 20, 'bold'), borderwidth=2, width=20)
    lbl.grid(row=2, column=3, pady=20)

    main()

    root.mainloop()
```

While debugging I am finding that, the process is started and the compiler goes to the method defined but not entering the method. I am unable to understand why?

The expected output is as below:

When the user press Y to start the timer, the Tkinter window should open and a countdown from 30 to 0 should begin as a process. While the countdown is running in the process, the next line in the main should execute and request for user input. If the user input "Y", the timer should pause as defined in pause() which should run as another process.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Global variables are global at most for one process. They can have other values in a subprocess.

Comment: The process running `update_label()` has no access to `lbl`, which exists only in the main process.  The process running `pause()` is accessing its own individual `paused` variable, which is not connected in any way to the variable used in other processes.  And the main process is not going to have a working GUI at all, because you do not have a running `mainloop()` until after the timer has been started and stopped - basically, `input()` has absolutely no place in a Tkinter program.

Comment: There's even another problem here.  Even if you converted from processes to threads here, to remain in the same process, you **CANNOT** touch any UI components from anything other than the primary thread.  This is a rock-solid law of user interfaces that applies to every framework on every operating system.  You can do your computations in a thread or process, but you have to use callbacks to have the UI updated in the main thread.